# Passing a list as arguments to function python

Tags: python

Scenario: I am trying to pass a list of strings to a function, as variable inputs.

**Issue:** Since the variables in the list are just for one of the arguments, I get the error `must be str, not list`.

The function hakes three inputs as arguments:

```
transformfile(path, name, id)
```

I have a list of names I want to pass:

```
list_names =['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3']
```

I tried passing it directly, but got the aforementioned error...

```
transformfile(path, list_names, id)
```

**Objective:** In this case, my objective would be to make the function run multiple times, for each of the names in list_names.

**Question:** Is it possible to do this kind of procedure, or do I have to simply call the function directly multiple times?

Comment: `for name in list_names: transformfile(path, name, id)`?

Comment: You'll need a `for` loop somewhere, it doesn't matter whether that's inside the function or outside it.

Comment: You can use destructuring: `transformfile(*list_names)`. The `*` tells python to expand the iterable.

Comment: @kpaul This is not what OP tries to do. Read the question carefully

Comment: @DeepSpace, Ah I see now. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function isn't made to receive multiple names, it can only handle single names and there is no way to call it that will change that.

Luckily, this is exactly what `for` loops are for:

```
for name in list_names:
    transformfile(path, name, id)
```

This is perfectly fine, normal, etc. Even if the function could receive a list, it'd probably have a for loop internally to do that.

Comment: It's probably an overkill but it might be a good opportunity to show that `partial` can be used here.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use **list comprehensions** if `transformFile` returns something:

```
result = [transformfile(path, n, id) for n in list_names]
```

Or even `map` builtin function with or without `functools.partial`:

```
result = map(lambda n: transformFile(path, n, id), list_names)

from functools import partial
result = map(partial(path=path, id=id), list_names)
```

Note: `map` returns an *iterable* so, if you want the result of each call, you need to create a list: `list(result)`